# How to verify if a player is currently signed in (or logon) to iOS Game Center or not?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, game-center

**Would anyone please show me a sample code written in C# that checks to see if a player is currently signed in (or logon) to iOS Game Center or not ?**

---

What I have done is the following:

I have this C# method below that will pop up the iOS Game Center window when players click on the "Game Center" button on my game:

```
    void ShowGameCenter ()
    {
        GKGameCenterViewController controller = new GKGameCenterViewController ();
        controller.Finished += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
            controller.DismissViewController (true, null);
        };
        AppDelegate.Shared.ViewController.PresentViewController (controller, true, null);
    }
```

This method kind of works well in the following way: if the player is currently signed in to Game Center, then this method pops up the real iOS "Game Center", and if the player is not currently signed in, then this method pops up an alert dialog that says "Game Center Unavailable. Player is not signed in."

***However, unfortunately, this method does NOT return some flag or boolean that indicates whether the player is currently signed in to Game Center or not. This flag or boolean is what I need to use for other parts of my game.***

So, I google "GKGameCenterViewController" and notice that iOS has defined these GKErrorCode constants:

```
enum {
   GKErrorUnknown = 1,
   GKErrorCancelled = 2,
   GKErrorCommunicationsFailure = 3,
   GKErrorUserDenied = 4,
   GKErrorInvalidCredentials = 5,
   GKErrorNotAuthenticated = 6,
   GKErrorAuthenticationInProgress = 7,
   GKErrorInvalidPlayer = 8,
   GKErrorScoreNotSet = 9,
   GKErrorParentalControlsBlocked = 10,
   GKErrorPlayerStatusExceedsMaximumLength = 11,
   GKErrorPlayerStatusInvalid = 12,
   ......
}
```

But, I have no idea which one of those constants corresponds to "**User not signed in to Game Center**", and I don't know how to get this error flag to use for my app either...

Here is the link to Apple Developer Tutorial webpage containing info about **GKGameCenterViewController**:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKGameCenterViewController_Ref/

Here is the link to Apple Developer Tutorial webpage that describes  **GKErrorCode**:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_ConstantsRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/GKErrorNotAuthenticated

---

Actually, I don't even think that my original C# method shown above would work for me in my particular scenario. The reason is that that method would pop up either the real iOS Game Center or the alert dialog that says "Game Center Unavailable. Player is not signed in". What I need is a different method that does **NOT** pop up either of those 2 windows, and **quietly returns a flag or boolean** to me to notify me whether the player is currently signed in to iOS Game Center or not.

Do you think that you can show me some other code samples that would do what I am looking for ? (Again, I would appreciate if you can show me the code in C# as I am using Xamarin to develop iOS games, and I can't understand Objective-C.)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In GameKit there is always **one** local player, but they might not currently logged in:

```
var gameStartButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
gameStartButton.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(40, 40, 100, 40);
gameStartButton.SetTitle("Start Game", UIControlState.Normal);
gameStartButton.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.AuthenticateHandler = async (UIViewController uiViewController, Foundation.NSError error) =>
    {
        if (uiViewController != null)
        {
            await PresentViewControllerAsync(uiViewController, true);
        }
        if (GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.PlayerID} : {GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated}");
            Console.WriteLine("Call a start game method...");
        }
        else
        {
            // no auth'd user, can your game use an anonymous one?
            var localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.GetAnonymousGuestPlayer("StackOverflow");
            Console.WriteLine($"{localPlayer.PlayerID}");
        }

    };
};
Add(gameStartButton);
```

> The GKLocalPlayer class is a special subclass of GKPlayer that represents the authenticated player running your game on the device. At any given time, only one player may be authenticated on the device; this player must log out before another player can log in.

Ref: [Apple's Doc GKLocalPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/index.html)

Note: Remember that iOS 10 will be removing the **Game Center App** from the phone, so it is now the developer's responsibility to present a `GKGameCenterViewController` or implement the interface and present your own customized version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried your code, but unless I make some mistake, your method does not seem to work...  In my test cases, regardless of whether I am currently signed in to Game Center or not, the code always goes to the line in your method that says "// Allow user to create acct/login : i.e. GKGameCenterViewController".  Do you have any suggestion ? Thanks.

Comment: @Thanh I did that from memory, The `GKLocalPlayer` is a singleton, I updated my code with an async-style example of using an in-app `AuthenticateHandler` to present the `GameCenter` login if needed... Just make sure that your app is registered with Apple otherwise you get an error dialog when trying to log in.

Comment: You wrote that "iOS 10 will be removing the Game Center App from the phone."  Would you please tell me if users still can manually logon to Game Center via the "Settings" app on iPhones ? (Wiki says that the "Settings" app still contains the "Game Center" button, but I am not sure yet...)

Comment: From what I've seen in the beta the game center in settings is still there as that will be a way for the user to logout/switch users (assuming the older games do not have that feature). Only the GC application is going away, so the developer needs to present the users achievements, ... Of course this is beta, so keep tracking it..

Comment: I tried your new method. Unfortunately, it does not compile because it complains that it does not know the function "PresentViewControllerAsync()"... But, that is OK. Let me keep trying to do more researches based on your method and your good suggestions... Thanks.

Comment: @Thanh https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIViewController.PresentViewControllerAsync/p/UIKit.UIViewController/

Comment: I am still trying to compile your code for now... But, I have a new question:  Will your code also pop up the "Game Center" login dialog if the user is not currently signed in to Game Center ? (As you know, iOS 10 does not have the "Game Center" app any more.)  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Thanh Yes, the `AuthenticateHandler` automatically passes the proper `UIViewController` as a parameter if needed and the `PresentViewControllerAsync` displays it to the user... they than can login if desired... they of course can cancel and then `Authenticated` would be false.